# How to get FutureBuilder return value to variable?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to get X value from FutureBuilder?

```
final url = FutureBuilder<List<Url>>(
    future: getUrlFromCache(),
    builder: (context,snapshot){var x = snapshot.data[1].uniform_resource_locator;},
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

check this out : [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

you can initilaize a global variable then assign a value inside the FutureBuilder but I dont know it's a good aproach doing this inside FutureBuilder.

```
// instead of creating dynamic types try to create static types.
var x; 

FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: _calculation, // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none:
        return Text('Press button to start.');
      case ConnectionState.active:
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Text('Awaiting result...');
      case ConnectionState.done:
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        x = snapshot.data[1].uniform_resource_locator;
        return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
    }
    return null; // unreachable
  },
)
```

Comment: How to access variable X from another class?

Comment: you can give parameter when you are navigating or when you are construct your object 
check this out : [Send data to new screen](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data)

Answer (score 1):

I think using 'x' will cause 'x' always will be equal to 'null'. It is possible to return it dynamically this way:

```
return ListTile(

            title: FutureBuilder(
              future: pair,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text( snapshot.data.title);
                } else {
                  return Text( 'Loading...');
                }
              },
            ),

          );
```

`FutureBuilder` always returns `Widget` type. Put your functionality inside the `FutureBuilder`.
In my case it returns Text widget. It is assigned to 'title:' and dynamically displayed on the screen as a ListTile.
Just replace the `Text` widget with the required `widget` that will use the data.